# Regex not preceded by href="

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, youtube, embed

So I am adding [embed][/embed] around youtube links in a WordPress environment, since if you use different fields for content input in the backend than the normale content editor, it won't do this automatically (even if you apply_filter the_content).

So, I found this regex which works perfect for my application:

```
$firstalinea = preg_replace('/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i', '[embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$2[/embed]', $firstalinea);
```

Except for one thing. If someone places a link to a YouTube-video instead of wanting to embed it, it also replaces and then the link does not work anymore.

```
<a href="https://youtu.be/xxxxxx">Link</a>
```

So, how to make the regex NOT work, if preceded by href="   ?

Thanks!

Comment: do a test with preg_match to see if it is preceded with an href

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: I also got this far which works with a regex tester, but throws php7 error:
`(?<!href=\")(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(?:www\.)?youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)`

Error:
preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '('

Answer (score 1):

Solved it:

```
$re = '/(?<!href=\")(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(?:www\.)?youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i';
$firstalinea = preg_replace($re, '[embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$3[/embed]', $firstalinea);
```